Seeking web browser - or extension - which will allow me to download any video on the page
Torch browser used to allow me to do this, but it is no longer supported.
Is there another browser that does, or an extension? Any video, from any page.

Hi Mawg. Are you familiar with yt-dlp?  It's an open source cross-platform project that accepts any URL as an input, and will do its best to download corresponding video(s), including videos on web pages.  It's not a browser or browser extension (it's a CLI tool), but may be helpful to you.  For more details, see: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp

The trouble is that it's not always easy to get at the URL. Even as a programmer who knows JavaScript, as some sites try to hide the URL. Thanks for trying, though. I might just dig through the browser cache

That's one of the wonderful features of yt-dlp.  If you pass it the page's main URL, it can often find the video's URL within the page.  It can be a big time-saver.  You can also use your browser's devtools to obtain the video's exact URL, but that's a bit more time consuming and tedious.

The above said, your question is a useful one, as a browser or browser extension that does this automatically would be nice.

I don't think you'll find anything 100% accurate. For example, yt-dlp mentioned in comments would have the issue of not being logged in to certain websites. Then there are some other factors:

various file formats
different ways of embedding the video, including iframes
infinite scroll or any other JavaScript loading the videos on the fly
server-side limitations, such as country blocks, direct entry prevention attempts, or anything alike
streaming the content, e.g. as .m3u8 playlist

etc.
I used Video Downloader Professional, for instance, and it was able to download 99% of what I wanted to download in the past. So you could give it a go. But in the end it all may depend on specific use case.

Well, like i said, Torch browser could do, because, as a browser, it knew exactly what the page contained. I wish that they had not discontinued it. Since it can be tricky to get at the URl, perhaps if I clear the browser cache, view the view, then examine the cache, that might help

You can use Open With browser extension to open the current page with any non-browser program with just two clicks.
Some sites may be tricky to download from, they are built differently, but there's a universal downloader, that can work with many sites - JDownloader. It has a feature to log in. Try if it helps.

Hi Havon, if you are associate with it, you are obliged to declare it so

@RohitGupta, do you mean, if I'm a developer of one of these apps? I'm not, I just use them.
